# Display individual rows when count > x

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with record_number(PRIMARY), owner_name, address in it.

I want to identify owner_name who own more than one property, and list each property owned by owner_name.

Something like:

```
record_number   | owner_name      |  address
1               | Smith           |  123 Main
7               | Smith           |  1 Some Street
12              | Smith           |  77 Dude Ln
19              | Jones           |  Some address
21              | Jones           |  Some Different address
47              | Jones           |  Yet another address
106             | Davis           |  You're getting the idea?
139             | Davis           |  All of these are different!
141             | Davis           |  They keep changing
158             | Davis           |  When will it end?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select record_number, owner_name, address
from your_table
where owner_name in
(
  select owner_name
  from your_table
  group by owner_name
  having count(*) > 1
)
order by owner_name, record_number
```